# chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener - changeInfo.status == 'complete' not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I tried this:

```
 chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
   if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {

     window.alert('test')

   }
 })
```

in my chrome extension. The problem is that I get the alert even though the images and the javascripts on the page didn't load up yet. For example when I'm on facebook and click on 'Home'. The message pops up immediately, although the loading icon keeps spinning for a few seconds. 
I need the message to pop up as soon as the the loading icon stops spinning and gets replaced by the site's favicon, because that's exactly when site has been loaded all it's content.

I hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem